# Filtering a Data frame with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data frame of Research results that I want to filter based on all four values being the same,

```
Trial 1 , Trial 2 , Trial 3 , Trail 4,
Pass      Pass      Pass      Pass 
Pass      Fail      Pass      Pass 
Pass      Pass      Fail      Fail
```

I have tried using the syntax `Df.trail1 == df.trail2` which works if Im trying to filter consistent results for Trial 1 and 2 , but If I want to filter consistent results for all for and I use 
`(df.trial1 == df.trial2) & (df.trial3 == df.trail4)` it does filter but it filters Pass Pass and Fail Fail as consistent. I want to filter only consistent results across all four tests using the same sort of syntax (simple code)

Thank you in advnace

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the most efficent way, but what about checking `(df.trial1 == df.trial2) & (df.trial2 == df.trial3) & (df.trial3 == df.trail4)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) for test if each row has unique number of values, but solution is slow if large `DataFrame`:

```
cols = ['Trial 1', 'Trial 2', 'Trial 3', 'Trail 4']

mask = df[cols].nunique(axis=1) == 1
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Or test, if each column has same values by first column with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
mask = df[cols].eq(df[cols[0]], axis=0).all(axis=1)
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[cols].eq(df[cols[0]], axis=0))
   Trial 1  Trial 2  Trial 3  Trail 4
0     True     True     True     True
1     True    False     True     True
2     True     True    False    False
```

Comment: Thanks the only problem is with this is the actual DF has lots of other content I have only inlcuded the columns Im interested in

Comment: @NicolaHodge - Answer was edited, use list of columns names for testing, here is called `cols`